# Python - Iterate through files in folder with partial string matches

Tags: python, string, join, operating-system, matching

I have to join/merge two different excel files that I've created from previous code, and I've made it so the files to be joined have the same string ending (testApple.xlsx, ...dummyApple.xlsx

I have managed to list the relevant files with the endings as the output, but I'm stuck on the final step of matching the two files with the ending 'Apple' for example. I'm sure it should be inside the nested for loop. I want to bring them into a dataframe then join the two matching files. I have it working elsewhere as

`inner_joinTest = df_testApple.merge(df_dummyApple, on = join_list, how = 'left')`

A sample code is here below:

```
listTest = ['apple', 'orange']

directory = r"C:\Users\Documents\Fruit"
for entry in os.scandir(directory):
    for i in listTest:
        if entry.is_file() and entry.name.endswith(i + ".xlsx"):
            print(entry.path)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do the merging outside of the nested for loop all you need to do is save the paths to a list or dictionary and you can do whatever you want with them.

```
listTest = ['apple', 'orange']
paths = {"apple":[], "orange":[]}

directory = r"C:\Users\Documents\Fruit"
for entry in os.scandir(directory):
    for i in listTest:
        if entry.is_file() and entry.name.endswith(i + ".xlsx"):
            paths[i].append(entry.path)
```

And now you have the paths you want grouped together in the paths dictionary so you can do whatever you want with them